# E/MediaPlayerNative: error (100, 1) on mediasession callback

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-mediasession

In my android application, I create a service which use MediaPlayer to play a remote stream.

Every time the stream is playing, the app shows a notification. This notification show a simple play/pause button and other info to start and stop the stream.

The service create the notification as follow:

```
private fun buildNotification() {
        val notification = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, this.notificationChannelId)
                .setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_pnr_round)
                .setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.colorPrimary))
                .setContentText(this.currentArtist)
                .setContentTitle(this.currentTitle)
                .setSubText(this.defaultAlbum)
                .setStyle(MediaStyle()
                 .setMediaSession(this.mediaSession.value.sessionToken)
                )
                .setContentIntent(PendingIntent.getActivity(applicationContext, 0, Intent(applicationContext, MainActivity::class.java), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT))


        if (this.mediaSession.value.controller.playbackState.state == PlaybackStateCompat.STATE_PLAYING) {
            notification.addAction(NotificationCompat.Action(
                    R.drawable.ic_pause, getString(R.string.notification_pause),
                    MediaButtonReceiver.buildMediaButtonPendingIntent(this, PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_STOP))
            )
        } else {
            notification.addAction(NotificationCompat.Action(
                    R.drawable.ic_play, getString(R.string.notification_play),
                    MediaButtonReceiver.buildMediaButtonPendingIntent(this, PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_PLAY))
            )
        }


        val notificationManager = applicationContext.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            val nc = NotificationChannel(this.notificationChannelId, this.notificationChannel, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW)
            nc.enableLights(false)
            nc.enableVibration(false)
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(nc)
        }

        notificationManager.notify(0, notification.build())
    }
```

To catch the notification actions, I use MediaSession callback

```
private val callbacks = object : MediaSessionCompat.Callback() {
    override fun onPlay() {
        play()
    }

    override fun onPause() {
        pause()
    }

    override fun onStop() {
        stop()
    }
}
```

Service and receiver are registered in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<service
    android:name=".services.MediaPlayerService"
    android:exported="false">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>
<receiver android:name="android.support.v4.media.session.MediaButtonReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

The problem is: every time I use the button in the notification, the app stalls, showing

```
"APP isn't responding"
```

Log shows this error:

```
E/MediaPlayerNative: error (100, 1)
                     error (100, 2)
E/MediaPlayer: Error (100,1)
E/MediaPlayer: Error (100,2)
E/MediaPlayerNative: error (1, -38)
E/MediaPlayerNative: error (1, -32)
E/MediaPlayerNative: error (1, -38)
E/MediaPlayer: Error (1,-38)
E/MediaPlayer: Error (1,-32)
E/MediaPlayer: Error (1,-38)
```

Using this service in other part of the application works as expected.

I suspect that
    MediaButtonReceiver.buildMediaButtonPendingIntent
is causing the trouble.

The problems seems to be limited to android 8 and 8.1, other version i tested (5, 6, 7.1, 9) seems to be free from this strange behavior.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I managed to solve this mistery

Changing

```
notificationManager.notify(0, notification.build())
```

with

```
startForeground(0, notification.build())
```

resolved the issue.

I'm waiting for the ASOP team in Issuetracker to clarify why this is happening only on Oreo.